# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. After running script

Tags: node.js

So i have a problem i am trying to run a javascript code but i just receive this i have tried everything i have come across the script im using is supposed to make a website the script starts fine but when i go to the website the console gives me this

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

```
at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
at /root/server.js:74:26
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /root/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
at next (/root/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
```

Comment: please format the paragraph into proper sentences ... also, please add a clear, answerable question to your post